# How to prevent transcluding directive to create new child scope for the form directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a problem with directive transclude and the form directive. As you may know, the form will end up in the "scope" if you add the "name"-property to the form tag, then you can check for form validation and so on.

My problem start when i put the form tag in a directive that uses transclude. I'm aware of how to deal with this problem with two-way data binding, as mention here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14484903/1029874  -- "use an object instead of a primitive"

But my form ends up in the transcluding directives scope. Here is an example of what i want to do.

```
 <div ng-controller="appCtrl">
   <widget>
     <widget-header>{{model.property}}</widget-header>
     <widget-body>
        <!-- The form will end up in "widget-body":s scope instead of appCtrl:s scope -->
        <form name="appForm" ng-submit="submit()">
          <input type="text" required ng-model="model.property" />
          <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
      </widget-body>
    </widget>
 </div>
```

And here is the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/WLksJ/1/

Is there a way that I can get around this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interesting question, but a problem that's easily avoided by using

```
<form name="appForm" ng-submit="submit(appForm.$valid)">
```

and checking the parameter in the submit function.

http://jsfiddle.net/udMJ7/

Another (perhaps better) option is to use `this` which is set to the scope of the last controller (in this case the form controller, which we want)

```
$scope.submit = function(){
    if(this.appForm.$valid){
        //post the form!!
    }
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/udMJ7/1/