# AngularJS directive scope not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

## Background

I have created a directive to keep track of selection on my table. The directive works with ng-repeat and adds a click event to every element created by the ng-repeat, when a user clicks on an element the directive updates the records selection atribute and sets the item as the selection on the controller scope for later use.

## Problem

The parent scope (CampaignDetailCtrl) is not getting updated by my directive click event, the selection attribute is never changing an is always null. I understand that using the `scope: false` causes the directive to use the parent scope but doesn't seem to work as planned.

## Question

How do I set the value of $scope.selection on my CampaignDetailCtrl from the directive?

## Controller

```
app.controller('CampaignDetailCtrl', ['$scope', 'CampaignService', '$stateParams', '$modal', function ($scope, CampaignService, $stateParams, $modal) {
$scope.selection = null;

//...
```

}])

## Directive

```
app.directive('selection', function () {
var directive = {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: false,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var selected_class = 'selected';

        var repeat_line = attrs.ngRepeat;

        if (!repeat_line) {
            throw 'selection must be used along side ngRepeat';
        }

        var repeat_parts = repeat_line.split(' in ');
        var selected_item = scope.$eval(repeat_parts[0]);

        scope.$watch(scope.selection, function(newVal, oldVal) {

        });

        /**
         * Item click handler
         */
        var handleClick = function (event) {
            selected_item.selected = !selected_item.selected;
            scope.selection = selected_item;

            if(selected_item.selected) {
                element.addClass(selected_class);
            } else {
                element.removeClass(selected_class);
            }
        };

        element.on('click', handleClick);
    }
};

return directive;
```

});

## HTML

```
<div ng-controller="CampaignDetailCtrl">
...

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>...</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr selection ng-repeat="channel in record.channels" ng-dblclick="edit(channel)">
        <td>{{...}}</td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
...
```

## Example

See simple jsBin example: http://jsbin.com/xoxez/3/

Comment: Please setup a demo. Thx

Comment: Please add your code to plunker/fiddle so that people can play with it.

Comment: Created a working example on jsBin  http://jsbin.com/xoxez/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a shadowing issue. You can read more about it at different places, but remember `ng-repeat` creates a new child scope for each item.

- http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/19/5-angularjs-antipatterns-and-pitfalls/
- [Two way binding not working in directive with transcluded scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481610)
- http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/directives/directive-to-directive-communication.html

To avoid scope shadowing, use a `.` in your ngModel:

```
$scope.selection = {
    noShadow: null
};

// later: $scope.selection.noShadow
```

Working example here: http://jsbin.com/teyofukerilo/1/

While this will just work fine, it would be better to have isolated scopes on your `selection` and wrap them into a `selected` directive. The selected directive would then be 'required' by the others and communication between them would be managed by the controller defined on the `selected` directive. You can read more about 'communicating' directives here: 
http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/sMgLuIxf02/angularjs-directive-to-directive-communication
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive (see require attribute)

Let me know if you need help implementing it.

Comment: Thanks, shadowing is a confusing issue, I had to read over several of the articles linked before I understood the problem. This has made me re thing the way I have structured parts of my application.