# Binding to a transclude in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm  not confident what I'm trying to do is correct, so please give me a "more correct" option if the whole premise is wrong.

I have an AngularJS 1.5.11 application. I am trying to create a generic modal html tag that can be used throughout the application wherever a modal is required. I have a page template that looks like this:

```
<form class="page-sidebar-container" data-name="mainForm">
    <div class="page-sections">
        <div class="form-columned form-columned-1">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="section column column-0 span-0" id="section-JobFromType">
                    <h4 class="section-heading">From Type</h4>


                    <div class="columns gutters-large">
                        <div style="display: table;margin: 18px 0px;">

                            <api-select label="Type" items="fromTypeItems" item="selectedFromType" required>
                            </api-select>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="section column column-1 span-0" id="section-JobToType">
                    <h4 class="section-heading">To Type</h4>
                    <div class="columns gutters-large">
                        <div style="display: table;margin: 18px 0px;">

                            <api-select label="Type" items="toTypeItems" item="selectedToType"
                                read-only="toTypeDisabled" required>
                            </api-select>


                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


<api-modal is-open="entitySelectOpen" label="{{entitySelectLabel}}">
    <modal-body>
        {{$id}}
        <api-select label="{{entitySelectParentLabel}}" items="entitySelectParentItems" item="selectedEntitySelectParent" required>
        </api-select>
    
        <api-select label="{{entitySelectChildLabel}}" items="entitySelectChildItems" item="selectedEntitySelectChild" read-only="entitySelectChildDisabled" required>
        </api-select>
    
        <api-select label="{{entitySelectEntityLabel}}" items="entitySelectEntityItems" item="selectedEntity" read-only="entitySelectEntityDisabled" required>
        </api-select>
    </modal-body>
    <modal-actions>
        {{$id}}
        <api-button label="{{modalPrimaryActionLabel}}" type="primary" icon="icon-checkmark" on-click="modalPrimaryActionClick"></api-button>
        <api-button label="Return" type="return" icon="icon-cancel" on-click="modalReturnActionClick"></api-button>
    </modal-actions>
</api-modal>
```

with the following controller:

```
(function (angular) {
    angular.module('views.jobcontrol', [
        'ngRoute',

        'components.formApiControlSelect',
        'components.formApiControlText',
        'components.formApiModal'
    ])
        .config([
            '$routeProvider',
            function ($routeProvider) {
                'use strict';
                var route = {
                    templateUrl: 'modules/apiViews/jobcontrol/jobcontrol-view.html',
                    controller: 'JobControlController',
                    reloadOnSearch: false,
                    caseInsensitiveMatch: true
                };
                $routeProvider
                    .when('/view/jobcontrol/:action/:jobNumber/?', route);
            }
        ]).controller('JobControlController', [
            '$scope',
            '$timeout',
            '$routeParams',
            function ($scope, $timeout, $routeParams) {
                'use strict';

                function generateMockGuid() {
                    var result, i, j;
                    result = '';
                    for (j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
                        if (j == 8 || j == 12 || j == 16 || j == 20)
                            result = result + '-';
                        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 16).toString(16).toUpperCase();
                        result = result + i;
                    }
                    return result;
                

                function option(label,value){
                    return {
                        value:value,
                        label:label
                    }
                }

                
                $scope.fromTypeItems = [option("test",1)];
                $scope.selectedFromType = null;
                $scope.$watch('selectedFromType', function (){
                    console.log("do something");
                });


                /* to type */
                $scope.fromTypeItems = [option("test",1)];
                $scope.selectedToType = null;
                $scope.toTypeDisabled = true;
                $scope.$watch('selectedToType', function () {
                    console.log("do something else");
                });

                

                
                /* entity select modal */


                $scope.selectedFromEntity = null;
                $scope.selectedToEntity = null;

                $scope.entitySelectParentItems = [option("parent 1", generateMockGuid()),option("parent 2", generateMockGuid()),option("parent 3", generateMockGuid())];
                $scope.entitySelectChildItems = [option("child 1", generateMockGuid()),option("child 2", generateMockGuid()),option("child 3", generateMockGuid())];
                $scope.entitySelectEntityItems = [option("entity 1", generateMockGuid()),option("entity 2", generateMockGuid()),option("entity 3", generateMockGuid())];

                $scope.selectedEntity = null;
                $scope.$watch('selectedEntity', function () {
                    console.log('selectedEntity has changed to ' + $scope.selectedEntity);
                });
                
                function clearModalSelections(){
                    console.log($scope);
                    $scope.selectedEntitySelectParent = null;
                    $scope.selectedEntitySelectChild = null;
                    $scope.selectedEntity = null;
                }


                $scope.modalPrimaryActionLabel = "Next";

                $scope.modalPrimaryActionClick = function(){
                    clearModalSelections();
                    $scope.entitySelectOpen = false;
                }

                $scope.modalReturnActionClick = function(){
                    clearModalSelections();
                    $scope.entitySelectOpen = false;
                }
            }
        ]);
})(window.angular);
```

The modal works, it has my `api-button`'s and `api-select`'s in it, and the `api-select`'s items are populated properly with the 3 options added to the `$scope.entitySelectParentItems`, `$scope.entitySelectChildItems` and `$scope.entitySelectEntityItems` arrays. The problem is that

```
$scope.$watch('selectedEntity', function () {
    console.log('selectedEntity has changed to ' + $scope.selectedEntity);
});
```

never gets called. If I move the three `api-select`'s out of the `api-modal > modal-body` and up the same level as the `api-modal` then everything works as expected (other than he elements being on the base page, rather than in the modal), but as soon as everything is inside the modal I lose access to when the user selects a value and what that value is.

I'm sure this must be something to do with the transclude having a seperate scope, but I'm confused. How can the `api-select` in the modal transclude access the main scope for its items to populate a select list and even updates if the list updates, but when the user selects something it isn't bound back to the scope the same way it does for the other `api-select`'s on the page. Am I using ng-transclude wrong? Is this an OK thing to do, but I am missing a step?

In case it matters, the javascript for `api-modal` looks like this:

```
angular.module('components.formApiModal',[
    'components.formApiButton'
])
.directive('apiModal', ['$timeout', '$compile', function ($timeout, $compile) {
    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'modules/apiComponents/generic/modal/modal-template.html',
        controller: 'apiModalController',
        transclude: {
            'body': 'modalBody',
            'actions': 'modalActions'
          },
        scope: {
            isOpen: "=",
            label: '@',
            actions: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    };
}])
.controller('apiModalController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);
```

and the template:

```
<div class="modal-backdrop modal-large" data-ng-class="{'modal-closed' : !isOpen }">
    <div class="modal-container">
        <div class="modal" data-ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()">
            <h1 class="modal-header" >{{label}}</h1>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-messages" data-ng-if="formPage.overrideConfirmationMessages.length">
                    <div class="form-header-errors">

                    </div>
                </div>
                <h4 class="section-heading" data-ng-if="section.altHelp">{{section.altHelp}}</h4>
                <div class="columns gutters-large">
                    <div ng-transclude="body"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" >
                <div ng-transclude="actions"></div>
               
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add `api-select` directive or a jsfiddle ?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481610/two-way-binding-not-working-in-directive-with-transcluded-scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14481610/two-way-binding-not-working-in-directive-with-transcluded-scope) check here a very detailed explanation

Comment: @BillP Thanks, that question looks like exactly what I was struggling to find. I'll give the answer there a try when I get back to it, it makes a lot of sense at least.

Comment: My suggestion is to stop using `$watch` and use callback functions instead. If you could provide api-select code, I would probably give you a reproducable example.